# How to set a default value through ng-init or data-ng-init?

Tags: angularjs

We have an address form and would like to set a default value of x to the input phone.

```html
<div
  class="form-group ms-mb-xs"
  data-ng-if="field.settings.display_type=='phone'"
>
  <label>
    {{field.label|msTranslate}}
  </label>
  <input
    type="tel"
    id="phone"
    class="form-control"
    data-ng-model="fields[field.name]"
    data-ng-intl-tel-input
    data-ng-init="fields[phone]=12345678"
  />
</div>
```

I have used data-ng-init and ng-init and tried putting a default value but it doesn't show on the front-end. Also tried `value="12345678"` but didn't work. Have also put the numbers in single quotes but still didn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/1823841) here to show the issue happening.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can do this.

1. Initialize your model variable with the value you need to show.
2. Use `ng-init` to execute code so that your model variable will be given a value.

It looks that you have tried the second option `data-ng-init="fields[phone]=12345678"`

The only reason why the option 2 doesn't work is that the controller updates the `fields[field.name]` with a blank value.

So, make sure you give a default value to the model variable if the intended value is blank. Something like this:

```
fields[field.name] = fromDB || 'a default value'
```